# Internet Explorer put my code inside unwanted div

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-9

Silly IE9 screwed up my layout of my aspx page.
In chrome it looks perfect:
[image]

However in EI9, it messed up my layout and made it look like this:
[image]

I've figured out why it looks the way it does. Apparently IE9 encapsulated my "save Note" button, description label, and description textbox in a div and made it float right. And the reason why the maincontent holder is displayed double, is because IE duplicated it but in the duplicated contentholder, it has not controls or anything in it. Just the background color.

Here is the html it generated:

```
 <div class="mainContentHolder">
    <span style="display: none;">
        <label>File</label>
        <label style="width: auto;" id="lblCaseFileID">2011630988 - </label>
    </span>
    <h3 id="quickNoteHeader">Quick Note: 2011630988 / 10/04/2012 08:47:12 <div style="float: right;">USES CURRENT DATE AND TIME<div></div></div></h3><div style="float: right;"><div>

    <span>
        <label class="inlineLbl">Description</label>
        <input style="width: 82%;" id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription" type="text">
        <span style="color: red; display: none;" id="ctl02" class="validation" title="Description is required">*</span>
        <input style="width: 75px;" id="saveNote" onclick="saveNewQuickNote()" name="saveNote" value="Save Note" type="button">
    </span>
    </div>
    <input id="hidCaseFileID" name="hidCaseFileID" value="2011630988" type="hidden">
    <input id="hidInvestigatorLoggedOnID" name="hidInvestigatorLoggedOnID" value="25" type="hidden">
</div>

<div class="mainContentHolder">
<div style="float: right;">
</div>
```

And this is my .aspx page:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="mainContentHolder">
    <span style="display:none;">
        <label>File</label>
        <label style="width:auto;" runat="server" id="lblCaseFileID"></label>
    </span>
    <h3 runat="server" id="quickNoteHeader">Quick Note</h3>
    <span>
        <label class="inlineLbl">Description</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:82%;" id="txtDescription" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator class="validation" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" ToolTip="Description is required" runat="server" />
        <input type="button" ID="saveNote" style="width:75px;" Value="Save Note" runat="server" onclick="saveNewQuickNote()" />
    </span>
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidCaseFileID" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidInvestigatorLoggedOnID" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Any suggestions? I have no idea why IE did this or how to prevent it/fix it
EDIT:
css:`.mainContentHolder
        {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            border: solid 1px #a1a1a1; 
            min-width:890px;
            width:920px;
            height:50px;
        }
        .mainContentHolder h3
        {
            font-size:13px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-right: 1%;
        }
        .mainContentHolder label
        {
            font-size: 11px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 1%;
        }
        .mainContentHolder input
        {
            width:70px;
        }
        .ui-dialog
        {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        .ui-widget-header
        {
            background: #8D122B;
        }
        .ui-datepicker
        {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        #quickNoteHeader
        {
           color: Green; 
        }`

EDIT - seems as though the layout does work in IE 10. But not IE9

Comment: Do you have a doctype set? e.g. are you rendering in Standards Mode or Quirks mode?

Comment: What are your class definitions?

Comment: I added the doc type in the main question

Comment: IE doesn't generate HTML, it reads it. If the HTML is wrong, you are outputting it wrong.

Comment: without the CSS for your classes, I can't replicate the problem

Comment: how can it be wrong if it is working in chrome/firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
```

and also set display block and width 100% of span

```
<span style="display:block;width:100%;">
        <label class="inlineLbl">Description</label>
        <input type="text" style="width:82%;" id="txtDescription" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator class="validation" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" ToolTip="Description is required" runat="server" />
        <input type="button" ID="saveNote" style="width:75px;" Value="Save Note" runat="server" onclick="saveNewQuickNote()" />
    </span>
```

Comment: I tried the block and width 100% but the block removed it from the mainContentHolder, or puts it over the area of the container and looks ugly. It still shows the same way as it does in my example in my question. IE still puts the 3 controls in a seperate div and floats it right

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</head>
```

Is not valid HTML.

You want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
```

And don't forget the closing `</html>` tag.

Comment: Thank you. but unfortunately I set my doc type and meta tag incorrectly in the question. In my actual code I have it is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

dear john when i put this code in my local website its working...

[image]

i think another css are conflict..

Comment: I have no other css files I am importing. Only the css I showed.

Comment: I do no understand this. When I went into the elements it shows that it added "<div style="float:right;"> and put the 3 controls in it. Why is it doing this? so confusing...